# Doctrine and Inheritance mapping problem with ManyToOne associations

Tags: doctrine

I have this problem.
I have 3 tables: tracking and lead_a and lead_b.
Tracking has 3 fields:

```
id ( PK )
area: varchar
lead_id: FK of one between lead_a and lead_b
```

SO I have three Entities: Tracking, LeadA and LeadB. Tracking has a ManyToOne relation with both LeadA or LeadB.

The business explanation is that I can be an instance of LeadA or LeadB, but both of us can have a "tracking" record.

I'd like to use `area` as discriminatorColumn, to have the props "lead" of the Tracking class be an instance of LeadA or LeadB in an API for tracking listing.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, you want to reference either "lead_a" or "lead_b" class to "tracking" and user "area" to discriminate between the leads? Seems easier to use a single "lead" class and use a discriminator column there to differentiate between the leads and have a single reference to tracking. Would you mind to explain further what you are trying to archive? And maybe add what you tried?